# What is beyond the supercritical fluid?

Tags: thermodynamics, states-of-matter, phase-diagram

I always wondered what was beyond the supercritical fluid. At first, I thought there was nothing, but then I thought well there be an ultra-critical fluid.

Is there even a phase beyond it? [image]

Comment: Different substances have different phase diagrams.  What substance are you interested in?

Comment: I don't think there is a mega-super-critical fluid, so I'm going to go with 'solid' at the higher pressures there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fermi Gas.**

Arguably the "next" state of matter would be [Fermi gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_gas), one where the pressure and temperature is so high that rather than classical physics (Boyle's law, Charles's law, Avogadro's law), quantum mechanical effects dominate.

[image: Graphic of states of Fermionic matter illustrating a point where QM effects take over.]

<sup>Wikipedia 2022, AG Caesar, public domain.</sup>

The sheer closeness of the atoms in this case means that the [Pauli exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle) exerts additional influence in a way equivalent to an increase in pressure/temperature.

It would normally only be found in the core of white dwarf stars and neutron stars. The conditions involved would prevent their stable-creation in a laboratory.

As a side-note, off the left hand end of the range of your graphic would exist a [Fermi condensate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermionic_condensate), a low-temperature superfluidic phase.

Comment: Thx for the information, I was searching the internet for days but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to upvote or accept the answer (using the green tick). @EndoBotm